# how to make changes in default fifo scheduler in hadoop 1.2.1?

Tags: hadoop, scheduler, fifo

i'm the new user of hadoop and i have a project to make some changes to the default scheduler "FiFoScheduler".
can anybody tell me from where to get the source code of fifo scheduler for hadoop version 1.2.1
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Here are the svn links:

- current trunk: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/trunk/
- all branches: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/branches/

You can also use git:

- current master: https://github.com/apache/hadoop
- branch 1.2: https://github.com/apache/hadoop/tree/branch-1.2
- [`FifiScheduler.java`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/f2ea555ac6c06a3f2f6559731f48711fff05d3f1/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/resourcemanager/scheduler/fifo/FifoScheduler.java)

Also try to read through this: [Using Git and Hadoop](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GitAndHadoop)